# Does domain aliasing affect performance or SEO?

Tags: dns, performance, ip-address, dns-lookup

I have checked my domain in http://ipinfo.info/html/ip_checker.php

It is showing the website is having two IPs (Aliasis) like `54.xx.xx.xx` & `103.xx.xx.xx`. Checked few popular websites and noticed not many websites are having more than one IP.

Those IPs are not being redirected to website too. Does this affect speed/performance or SEO of the website?

Comment: Why do you have 2 IP addresses short of fail-over or load-balance? If it is not for fail-over or load-balance, I would drop one. Short of routing issues, having 2 IP addresses should not effect speed and has nothing to do with SEO generally.

Comment: Actually its not my personal website, its company's. And yes, we use load-balance and fail-overs also, I believe. So this this info is very much useful to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. Then the two IP addresses make sense. However, both IP addresses should not go through the same network. The exception I can see is in trusting a hosting company. I was a web host in a former life, now retired to farming, antiques, property investment, etc. I had many connections, networks, etc. so it all worked fine. As long as the speed is good for both IP addresses, then there should be no effect. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not affect in SEO. Google own IP is changing from time to time also with location. It is mainly because of load balancing.

Many of website using cloud based hosting, and their bucket location is various based on user location. Choosing best bucket region can help developer to save money, because ingress and egress traffic are depend on cloud server location. Also when same region bucket cached by CDN then rate are different. So there are some valid reason to use different bucket region (And so one multiple IP address) to host website.

And if you're using IP checker tools, then you should note that, they are returning their server IP address based on location. So if you try to ping same website from other location then server IP may be different, so don't focus on third party tools, because their location is fixed.